# How to get ADDED friends that are in a Contact List?

Tags: c#, .net, skype4com

I know that I can get all my contacts with Skype.Friends. However I want to get only contacts that are in a specific Contact List.

How can I do it?

I DO NOT want THIS

```
ArrayList UserList = new ArrayList();
var SkypeClient = new SKYPE4COMLib.Skype();
foreach (SKYPE4COMLib.Group Group in SkypeClient.CustomGroups)
{
    foreach (User User in skype.Friends)
    {
        //Adds the usernames from the specified group in the list.
        UserList.Add(User.Handle);
    }
}

//Writing the list in a label
string s = "";
foreach (string str in UserList)
{
    string s2 = s + str + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

I just need list of Added contacts not all but just added ones

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085275/how-to-get-friends-that-are-in-a-contact-list

Comment: Reply Damith:

I actually read this but it reads all contacts not just added ones :D I need to read contacts you have accepted as friend.... Not this

Comment: And just now I saw how old this questions is. :)

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I edited my answer. Hope this'll work for you because I haven't actually tried it myself yet. :)

```
    ArrayList UserList = new ArrayList();
    var SkypeClient = new SKYPE4COMLib.Skype();
    foreach (User User in skype.Friends)
    {
        if (User.BuddyStatus == SKYPE4COMLib.TBuddyStatus.budFriend)
        {
            UserList.Add(User.Handle);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't want usergroup there :'| I want ALL added friends (all contacts that accepted friend request)

Comment: Well your initial question is not really describing that pretty well... Anyway, I'll edit my answer now.

Comment: @XeJuicY : I noticed I didn't put the `@` in the comment, so I just wanted to know if you have seen my edit. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to try it in C#

```
ArrayList UserList = new ArrayList();
    var SkypeClient = new SKYPE4COMLib.Skype();
    foreach (User User in skype.Friends)
    {
        if (User.IsAuthorized == True)
        {
            UserList.Add(User.Handle);
        }
    }
```

Try that

Answer (score -1):

I do not know C# but I do know vb.net. In vb.net you would do

```
    For Each l As User In oSkype.Friends
        If l.IsAuthorized = True Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(l)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Since you have tried to answer in C# also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30959113/1364007) you should delete one answer and maybe include both C# and VB.NET in a single answer. Also please explain your code rather than just posting it without saying what it does / how it applies or helps, etc. Thanks.